# How to add Google AdWords to a public Trello board?

Tags: trello, google-adwords

I have a public Trello board which needs to be promoted on Google. Is there a way I can add Google AdWords to this board?

Comment: You don't have to add anything to a website to start promoting it with Google Adwords, do you? You just create your ads and put any URL you want there.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Zapier for the purpose. Where it will zap data between Trello and Google AdWords. Please check the link below for detailed information.

[google-adwords-trello](https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-adwords/trello/)

Comment: Not clear if it's a currently supported feature on Zapier. Can you please explain it with details?